# MySQL UNION - detect what of several SELECTs return result

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two SELECT queries merged with UNION. Here is MySQL query:

```
SELECT `id`,`type`,`text`
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE position = '1' 
   AND status = '1' 
   AND targeting = 'all'
UNION
SELECT `id`,`type`,`text` 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE position = '1' 
   AND status = '1' 
   AND targeting LIKE '%US%'
```

How can I find out what of these two SELECT queries executed with TRUE in order to fetch result from needed row?

Answer (score 7):

You can add an extra column to your query that returns a different constant depending on which part of the query succeeded:

```
SELECT 'query1' AS `src`, `id`, `type`, `text`
FROM my_table
WHERE position = '1' AND status = '1' AND targeting = 'all'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'query2' AS `src`, `id`, `type`, `text`
FROM my_table
WHERE position = '1' AND status = '1' AND targeting LIKE '%US%'
```

Also in this case you don't need a UNION at all:

```
SELECT
    targeting LIKE '%US%' AS `targeting_like_us`,
    targeting = 'all' AS `targeting_equals_all`,
    `id`,
    `type`,
    `text`
FROM my_table
WHERE position = '1'
AND status = '1'
AND (targeting LIKE '%US%' OR targeting = 'all')
```

Comment: @Mark Byers and how can I use it on my PHP script? Tell, please!

Comment: @ilnur777: What do you have so far? Can you post your current PHP script?

Comment: @Mark Byers I need a SELECT query that will fetch one row from the my_table depending on targeting set on the row and display it on the advertisement place. the advertisemnt will be shown only for targeted visitors or for all visitors as I have random banner display script.

Comment: I'd use a CASE statement to return the all vs %US% in a single column, returning 1 or 2 depending on the match.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Could you post an example? Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Byers Is this a condition I have to use on PHP scipt: `if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){ echo 'display_banner'; } else { echo 'sorry, no banner found...'; }` ?

Comment: @ilnur: What if it returns two rows? Your example code will produce `sorry, no banner found...` which seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Mark Byers May be need to make a priority for targetting in the MySQL query? Like the priority first should select with targetting = 'all'. If nothing found, then selecting with targetting LIKE '%US%'?

Comment: @Mark Byers Forgot to mention that I have LIMIT 0,1 on the SELECT queries. So it will always fetch only one row.

Comment: @ilnur777: You can use `ORDER BY condition DESC LIMIT 1` to ensure that if there are two rows, one with condition = true and another with condition = false then the row with the condition = true is returned, e.g. `ORDER BY targetting = 'all' DESC LIMIT 1`.